# How to change the table row color onclick function in java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to change the selected table row color using inline Javascript in HTML I am trying in this way

**onclick="this.style.backgroundColor='blue'"**
I am writing this in

```html
<tr onclick="this.style.backgroundColor='blue'">
   <td>row1</td>
   <td>row2</td>
</tr>
```

When I click on row1 that row color should change to blue.When I again click on row2 then row1 background color reset to normal and row2 background color become blue How can I achieve this.

Comment: You need to understand that the texts **row1** and **row2** are in the same table row. `td` represents cells and not rows (*which is represented by the `tr`*).

Comment: the rows are dynamic so i cant write it on td

Comment: i understand, but your example code show 2 cells and not 2 rows.

Comment: toggling a class is so much easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need a single lined js, then (for modern browsers):

```css
.selected {
  background-color: coral;
}


table {
    border-spacing:0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr onclick="var s = this.parentNode.querySelector('tr.selected'); s && s.classList.remove('selected'); this.classList.add('selected');">
    <td>row1</td>
    <td>row2</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr onclick="var s = this.parentNode.querySelector('tr.selected'); s && s.classList.remove('selected'); this.classList.add('selected');">
    <td>row1</td>
    <td>row2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect answer . Expected the same result . thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it using inline javascript.

I would use something like this (*for modern browsers*)

```js
// delegate the event handling to the table
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var closestCell = e.target.closest('td'), // identify the closest td when the click occured
      activeCell = e.currentTarget.querySelector('td.selected'); // identify the already selected td

  closestCell.classList.add('selected'); // add the "selected" class to the clicked td
  if (activeCell) activeCell.classList.remove('selected'); // remove the "selected" class from the previously selected td

})
```

```css
.selected {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>row1</td>
    <td>row2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is good but i am doing in angular where the table is a component so i cant paste the java script code in that page :( So needed single line code or any other way to implement this

Comment: @ShreenivasKulkarni then post your angular code and tag your question with the angular tag.